# Removing an element from a list in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

Suppose I have the following list:

```
x <- list(a = c(1, 2), b = c("a", "c"), c = 1:10)
```

In R, I can remove the first element using the following two methods:

```
x[-1]
x[1] <- NULL
```

I'm trying to do same thing in Rcpp, but I can't figure it out. Following code just assigns `NULL` to the first element.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List removeElement(Rcpp::List x)
{
  x[0] = R_NilValue;
  return(x);
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List removeElement(Rcpp::List x, int j)
{
  IntegerVector idx = seq_len(x.length());
  return(x[idx != j]);
}
```

Or if you want the indices to start from 0 use

```
IntegerVector idx = seq_len(x.length()) - 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I didn't know that we can use `x[idx != j]`. For my question, I'm looking for a more general solution. I want to decide the `j` within the function using if-else statements and there might be many elements to be removed. For example, I might want to remove all list elements with length 2.

Comment: Use `x[!sapply(x, !isLengthTwo)]`, where `isLengthTwo` is some function taking a `SEXP` and returning a `bool`. Or, in general, you can use `x[sapply(x, f)]` for some function / functor of your choosing.

Comment: You are only selecting elements with length 2 now, Kevin ;-)

Comment: I solved my problem using the answer. Using a loop I removed elements one by one from the end.. @KevinUshey thanks for the input. I believe your answer is general enough..